# How to iterate over a list in rml file of ReportLab

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-templates, reportlab

I have dictionary created in python for e.g.

```
dictionary_list = [{'1':1,'2': 2,'3': 3},{'1': 1,'2':2,'3':3,'4':4},{'1':1,'2':2}]
```

Now I want to iterate over this dict using python syntax. I tried this:

```
{% for (key_o, val_o) in dictionary_list.items %}
```

but it does not work. Then i tried this as previous syntax was not helpful.

```
{% for dictionary in dictionary_list %}
     {% for (key_o, val_o) in dictionary.items %}
        {{ val_o }}
     {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

But still it is not printing `val_o's` value.I am getting frustrated since I am not able to iterate over the dictionary list in Report Markup Language (RML File) of [Report lab](http://www.reportlab.com/software/documentation/). Please guide me, Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

It's a list of sets, not dicts:

```
>>> [ type(x) for x in [{1,2,3},{1,2,3,4},{1,2}]]
[<type 'set'>, <type 'set'>, <type 'set'>]
```

Try something like this:

```
set_list = [{1,2,3},{1,2,3,4},{1,2}]
{% for item in set_list %}
     {% for x in item %}
        {{ x }}
     {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

**Update:**

As parenthesis are not allowed in django tags so you should not use them. This should work fine:

```
{% for key_o, val_o in dictionary.items %}
```

And if you only want the values from the dicts not keys then just use dict.values:

```
{% for val_o in dictionary.values %}
```

Comment: Sorry for wrong description of question, but you are right for my previous description, So can you please update your answer for the updated question of mine , thanks